# require_once at symfony

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I'm making now things with php + Symfony2 framework, and I have the following code:

```
require_once("one_file.php");
require_once("another_file.php");
```

... and so on.

The problem is, how to "Symfonyze" these uncomfortable require sentences, and after, how to include these files in the Symfony2 package?

We've thought about two possibilities:

1. Include the file at `/vendors` directory of symfony, or
2. Include each class as a service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If these classes reside inside bundle then you could use as below:
Suppose your bundle name is AcmeDemoBundle. Place this file inside Acme/DemoBundle/Model/

```
  //one_file.php
   namespace Acme/DemoBundle/Model;
   class one_file {
   ...........
   }
```

To use this file inside your controller or any other file:

Here for Acme/DemoBundle/Controller/UserController.php

```
   namespace Acme/DemoBundle/Controller   
   use Acme/DemoBundle/Model/one_file
    class UserController {
    public $one_file=new one_file();
    }
```

In php 5.3 onwards, namespaces has been introduced. You should probably look at namespaces and its uses in php documentation

Comment: Since there's no accepted answer yet, I would suggest this one as the right one because it worked for me.

Comment: Worker! Thank you so much and sorry for the delay

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the PSR-0 standard to let the autoloader handle this. See https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md and http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-0 .

Or you could keep your files as is, and tell composer to require them each time : http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a folder in your acme folder like lib puts these files in lib folder then   use this statement

```
use Acme\DemoBundle\lib\Abc; // its your class name
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to follow these other answers, especially the approved one, but if you are using a third party library with tons of PHP files, you can do `require_once(__DIR__.'/path/to/file.php')` as a quick fix.

Comment: Thanks, that's the only working solution for me it seems.