# Symfony failed to open stream: no such file or directory

Tags: php, symfony

I have some general functions in myBundle/Controller/functions.php and I want to include this php file in another php.

In myBundle/Service/myService.php I do:

```
require_once ('../Controller/functions.php');
```

but when running i keep getting the error message 'ContextErrorException: Warning: require_once(functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ..../myBundle/Services/myService.php line ..'

Looks so stupid, it must be something simple i Guess.  Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: You should be taking advantage of namespaces and use keywords instead of include or require.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 4):

I think you did not use **namspace** in your class. If you use namespace , then it is easy to include those file more easy and comfortable.

If your name space is :

```
Acme\Bundle\BlogBundle
```

Then include it in your desired class using:

```
use Acme\Bundle\BlogBundle;
```

Also you need to meet the rules defined in PSR-0 (https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) to get it work.

Comment: The functions I wanna include are no classes...  require_once() is still valid php command. not?

Comment: require_once(), include() this type row php function is not available in Symfony2. Hence your method is not inside class, so you should create a class and put this function inside class. Remember, always use namspace. here you get your comments answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410946/require-once-at-symfony

Answer (score 0):

Searching the Symfony sources I found a way to include the php file. From within a php-source in myBundle/Services use

```
require_once __DIR__."/../Controller/functions.php";
```

instead of

```
require_once "../Controller/functions.php";
```