# How to include any php in Controller

Tags: php, symfony, controller, include

I would like to call a php file inside the controller, but it appears an error like this:

```
Fatal error: Class 'AppBundle\Controller\DOMPDF' not found in ....
```

Here my code :

```
require_once(__DIR__.'/../../../../dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream('report_'.$name.'.pdf');
```

If anyone can help me? thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [require\_once at symfony](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410946/require-once-at-symfony)

Comment: Have you checked if `__DIR__.'/../../../../dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php'` is the correct path for that file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For utilize the DOMPDF PHP Library in a symfony2 project you can use the [DompdfBundle](https://github.com/SlikNL/DompdfBundle). Following the instruction in the github page.

After the installation, you can use it as a service, as described in the doc:

```
$dompdf = $this->get('slik_dompdf');

// Generate the pdf
$dompdf->getpdf($html);

// Either stream the pdf to the browser
$dompdf->stream('report_'.$name.'.pdf');
```

Hope this help

Comment: Oke, I will try this .

Comment: Moreover remember that any php library that hasn't a bundle, could be load with symfony2 autoload facility